# Cycles render engine is not rendering anything

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I've looked everywhere in SE for a solution, nothing seems to be working. For no obvious reason cycles rendering is not working, as you can see in the screenshot, here's what I've tried to do:

1. check/uncheck sequencer in post processing tab.
2. changing between global and local view.
3. switching between layers.

is there anything else I can try? 
[image]

here's the blend file:
[image]

Comment: Please upload your blend file, the screenshot just can't schow everything

Comment: @schustudrai would you please suggest a file sharing method?

Comment: try [Blend-exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Comment: I cannot check the .Blend right now, however make sure your render layers are set up. https://www.blender.org/manual/render/post_process/layers.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your camera is pointing to nothing... if you press numpad 0, you see why you get that "empty" render...

select the camera and press CTRL + numpad 0, you now see the selected camera points to the scene objects, then hit F12, you get what you expected:

[image]

**update**

here's the result after appending all object and actions from your file into a blank new file

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, but when I press animation the problem persists, pressing `Ctrl`+ `F12` works fine but the button shows the same problem

Comment: ...this is really weird... F12 and CTRL+F12 work, but hitting "render" and "animation" not....?!? I guess this file could have become corrupted, I tried this: open a new file, delete all, append all objects from the old file... it seems to behave well...

Comment: you can append actions also... I edited the post showing the "animation" button works in this way...

Comment: Thank you so much, but now the rendering is all messed up right now, it looks jerky with a lot of noise...

Comment: yes, sorry, I set 10% resolution and 32 render samples to speed up the animation render... :) it was 128 samples before...

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't the problem, I'll edit the question, so you would see what I mean

Comment: Everything is working fine now, thank you so much for your time

Comment: Good! I'm happy that you solved it!

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem, maybe for different reasons, but it might help other people. I had an animation strip from a previous project on the video editor, deleting the stuff that was on the video editor solved it