# Sheep it render farm outputs blank frames

Tags: rendering

I came across [Sheep It](https://www.sheepit-renderfarm.com/index.php), the render farm. I'm uploading my .blend file, the output is just blank photos, it's not showing anything. The thing is that  [I had a problem with the file](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65214/cycles-render-engine-is-not-rendering-anything), I don't know if the problem mentioned here has something to do with the fact that clicking animation button would render only one blank frame, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + F12 is working just fine, I hope I made my problem clear.

Here is my blend file:

[image]

Comment: Did you pack or include all external data, textures and relevant dependencies in the file uploaded to the render farm? Does it come out  blank when you render it locally on your pc? If not report it to ship. It not here

Answer (score 2):

Your active camera is a plane. Select your camera and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>.